# How can i find a bucket created by MerchantsCenter in Google Cloud Plattform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-ads-api, google-merchant-center

i wanted to import my shopping-feeds from Google Cloud Plattform into Merchantcenter.

So i created a bucket automatically in the Merchant Center, it shows me the name in MC but i cant find the bucket in my Google Cloud Plattform.
I know it is somewhere, because i cannot create a bucket with the same naming!
Is there a code where i can see where it is? In which project for example( i looked in all i have and couldnt find it). It is definetly the same email i logged in into MC and GCP.

Would nice if someone could help me...

Queen regards

Joschi

Comment: If you know the name of the bucket you can use the CLI `gsutil` to list and access the contents of the bucket. However, do not upload data to the bucket as Merchant Center will delete objects not managed by Merchant Center. This document might help you https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/185963

Comment: as mentioned by @JohnHanley you should confirm that you have access to the bucket by using gsutil, if you can use the bucket with gsutil there might be something related with UI, taking in mind that the recommended way to manage the bucet is by gsutil